# open crystal report visual studio 2008 in visual studio 2017

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017

I am migrating a `WinForm Application` from `Visual Studio 2008` to `visual Studio 2017`.
My Visual studio 2008 has severals `Crystal Reports`.  I have the same Crystal Reports installed from Visual Studio 2008.

I am working with Oracle Database. All connection to Database are working properly.

I have a `winForm` page where I load a ReportViewer. On `form_load` event I have this code

```
 Private Sub frmPlanification_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If mDataSource Is Nothing Then Me.Close()
        Dim Reporte As New rptPlanificacionModificadaLog
        Dim Margenes As New CrystalDecisions.[Shared].PageMargins

        Reporte.SetDataSource(mDataSource)
```

On line

```
Reporte.SetDataSource(mDataSource)
```

This is working fine in visual Studio 2008. But in Visual studio 2017 got this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.DataSourceException' occurred
>   in CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion.dll
>       Additional information: Error to connect to unknown database

I do not know if is an error on database or Crystal report version.

Answer (score 0):

I have to changed my App.Config.

```html
  <!--<startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>        
    </startup>-->

     <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    </startup>
```